# Tile Windows vertically in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, desktop

I'm currently running win 8.1, mostly with "normal" (as opposed to metro) apps, and one things bugging me - Is there a way to tile two windows vertically like there was in 7? I've tried task manager and selecting multiple items, but you can't select more than one item.

Comment: Yes?  The desktop behavior wasn't changed.  You can tile Windows Explorer windows and any x86-x64 Windows application you want.

Comment: But how do I do it? I can do it horizontally with Windows key + Left/Right. Up maximises the window, and down Restores down. In win7 the only way I knew of involved the task manager, and clicking multiple programs, but as I've said, this doesn't work in 8.

Comment: How do you do what exactly?  I was able to minimize all of my windows except this browser window by shacking it just like I did in Windows 7.  I was then able to stack all the Windows just like I did in Windows 7.

Comment: ..... I've actually missed that option. I don't know how. Only issue with it is it does all active windows (which can be ~10 per screen for me) any way you know of to only do certain windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Ramhound's comments, I found the option I was looking for, where it always has been. Minimise all of the windows, open all the windows you want to stack, and right click on the taskbar, and click show windows stacked.

Answer (score 0):

The show windows stacked did not work for me with have multiple monitors.

What did work was using the `Win+Arrow` keyboard shortcuts until the windows were stacked on half of the screen, in 2x2 configuration. Then I dragged one end with the mouse to fill the rest of the screen.

It is better to stack them on the side of the screen you share with the other screen. That way when you stretch the window to the other way, you can fill the whole screen without stepping over.